# PDO SQLSRV displays errors - while exposing the database structure

Tags: php, pdo, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.3, sqlsrv

I'm currently using the following things in my project:

- Symfony 2.3.11
- SQL Server 2008
- Doctrine 2 (latest) + pdo_sqlsrv (5.5)
- PHP 5.5.3

I'm doing the following when I call `$em->flush()`:

```
try {
    $this->em->flush();
} catch (\PDOException $e) {
    switch ($e->getCode() {
        case /*Depending of the codes*/:
            throw new \Exception(/*Message that hides the real error and just gives the code and a user-friendly message*/);
    }
}
```

However, this action still displays any SQL Server errors, exposing the query and the internal structure to the user. What should I do to catch those errors and convert them to better messages? Thank you beforehand.

Comment: Specify the symfony environment are you referring to dev environment  or production environment

Comment: It's the production environment, forgot to mention that.

Comment: It might helps you http://forum.symfony-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=70585

Comment: Thank you, but I'm doing everything described there and it still displays the errors.

Answer (score 0):

It displays the exception because you are throwing the exception. Do not throw them or write an exception listener or handle them after the catch block. Refer these [googled](https://symfonybricks.com/en/brick/custom-exception-page-404-not-found-and-other-exceptions) and [from symfony](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html)

Comment: Wait, are those PDO exceptions (which I'm not sure if they are classified as such though, they are more along SQL Server error messages displayed) or can I classify them as a kernel exception?

Comment: you deal with them based on the exception ??

Comment: Yes, I do. But what I get as the error message is something along the lines of `Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'LastName', table 'Northwind.dbo.Employees_2'; 
column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.` (this is an example taken from somewhere else, but I hope it's clear enough to show the kind of messages I'm getting). I've been handling them as PDO exceptions because otherwise I don't know what kind of error or exactly what component fails here. I've been googling a lot and have found nothing.